# Nested For Loops Skipping a whole line while iterating? Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

Since this is a homework assignment and for its integrity, i'll be using a mock code as an example. The model I was given as an example uses switch statements so I attempted to mimic the result using if/else if/else.

```
for (int i = 0, i < 26; i++)
char ch = word[i]
 type = testChar(ch); 

            switch (type) 
            {
            case 0:
                std::cout << "digit" << std::endl;
                break;

            case 1:
               std::cout << "letter" << std::endl;
               break;


            case 3:
               std::cout << "None" << std::endl;
               break;
            }
```

homework.txt contains

```
!while true!
line1
line2
```

main contains

```
def main():
    with open('homework.txt','r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    sentencesbank = data.splitlines()
    for sentences in sentencesbank:
          for letter in sentences:
              type = test(letter) #a test that just returns if the letter is a digit(0) or letter(1)
              if (type == 0):
                     print("digit")
                     break
              elif(type ==1):
                    print("letter")
                    break
              else:
                   print("none")
                   break
```

is the general gist of how my code is working. The expected output would have been

```
none
letter
letter
letter
letter
letter
none
letter
letter
letter
letter
none

letter
letter
letter
letter
digit
none

letter
letter
letter
letter
digit
none
```

But instead what actually happened was it would go

```
none
letter
letter
```

It reads the first character of the first line and then skips the remainder of that line.

By chance could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Given your code and example input, it would print only `none letter letter`, not what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` statement stops any iteration going to the outer level next to the current nested level. As your code has a sequence of `if`, `elif`  and `else` all them with the `break` statement, this behavior described by you is the expected behavior.

The thing is that in C++ when one case is evaluated to true, all following cases are also evaluated to true. Because of this, the break is needed. As others already pointed in the comments, just remove the breaks and your code will work properly.

Comment: I see. The code I was given as an example was written in C++ and used switch statements instead of the if/else if/else but when I was doing some research, I had found out that python does not have a built in switch function. By chance would you be able to provide an example that would mimic my code using switch statements? I'll update the main post to show the switch statement example.

Comment: @tonydo Using `if`/`elif` is perfectly fine, just remove the `break`s.

Comment: @tonydo I edited my answer to explain why the breaks are needed in C++.

Answer (score 2):

The `break` in each of your `if` statements is breaking out of the `for letter in sentences:` loop. Remove them.